# EC2 instance image on VirtualBOX?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vmware, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is there any way of getting the saved EC2 instance image and running it on virtualbox on my personal computer?

Comment: There's a link on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920993/convert-amazon-ec2-ami-to-virtual-or-vagrant-box) describing how to [manually copy the filesystems into VM disks](http://smashingboxes.com/ideas/how-to-convert-ec2-ami-to-vmdk-for-vagrant).  This technique may be helpful if you did not create the instance by importing a virtual machine, and this cannot use the official way.

Answer (score 7):

The official way is only if it was originally imported into EC2

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExportingEC2Instances.html

> If you have previously imported an instance into Amazon EC2, you can
>   use the command line tools to export that instance to Citrix Xen,
>   Microsoft Hyper-V, or VMware vSphere. Exporting an instance can be
>   useful when you want to deploy a copy of your EC2 instance in your
>   on-site virtualization environment.
>
> **You cannot export an instance unless it was previously imported into AWS**

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you can directly import/export ec2 and virtualbox/vmware images.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/

Comment: This is only available to instances which used the vm import feature previously. You can't export AMI based instances using this.

Answer (score 2):

The amazon tool is very restrictive. But you can dump your EBS, download it and make a VDI image out of it. I have done it with two of my EC2 instances and described the steps on my blog.

http://diogomelo.net/blog/16/export-amazon-ec2-instance-to-virtualbox